# Proguard and Preference DataStore

Tags: android, proguard, datastore

I use proguard on my project which is used android [DataStore](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore). It worked fine without proguard. But when it is obfuscated with proguard the following error occured:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Field preferences_ for f.k.k.h not found. Known fields are [public f.k.k.l.k0 f.k.k.h.i, public static final f.k.k.h f.k.k.h.j, public static volatile f.k.k.l.x0 f.k.k.h.k]
        at f.k.k.l.s0.K(Unknown Source:62)
        at f.k.k.l.s0.y(:6)
        at f.k.k.l.s0.x(Unknown Source:12)
        at f.k.k.l.a1.a(:32)
        at f.k.k.l.a1.b(Unknown Source:4)
        at f.k.k.l.x.r(:4)
        at f.k.k.h.s(:2)
        at f.k.k.k.b(:2)
        at f.k.i.e(Unknown Source:48)
        at f.k.i.f(:2)
        at f.k.i.d(:4)
        at f.k.i$b.e(:4)
        at i.n.j.a.a.l(:2)
        at d.a.p0.run(:4)
        at d.a.f2.a.u(Unknown Source:0)
        at d.a.f2.a$a.run(:7)
```

There is no proguard rule mentioned in the official document. Should I add some rules to my project to prevent DataStore from obfuscation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It was solved when I add the following rule to my project:

```
-keep class androidx.datastore.*.** {*;}
```

I have reported it to the google, you can follow it there:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/168580258

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I had problems when implementing the datastore proto, which stores objects.
For me it solved like this:

my build.gradle(Module) looks like this

```
 //  DataStore Proto
implementation  "androidx.datastore:datastore-core:1.0.0"
implementation  "com.google.protobuf:protobuf-javalite:3.14.0"
implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences:1.0.0"
```

proguard-rules.pro

```
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite* {
   <fields>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

adding to this this because I had a similar issue very recently, perhaps it may help someone else until it is fixed.

If the above solution provided above for proto-datastore does not work, put the new proguard rule in the Module's `consumer-rules.pro` instead.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35283668)